# How can I remember selected days of the week and its value?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating an android application which allow the user to put his tab and its exercises, set and reps.

I'm retrieving the days of the week that the user checked, so I'd like to take the days to another activity. These are the step:

USER CHECK DAYS OF THE WEEK -> NEW ACTIVITY WELL BE OPEN, IT WILL ASK YOU TO PUT TWO MUSCOLAR GROUPS FOR EVERY DAY YOU CHOOSE.

Example:
User choose: Monday, tuesday and saturday, next step, MONDAY: lat and shoulder ; TUESDAY: triceps and biceps; The problem is that I'm not able to understand how can I remember the days that the user choose. I tried to get some algorithms but I'm stack to the first day he choose and I don't know how to increase it.

Xml image:

[First step](http://mygym2017.altervista.org/Screenshot__39_.png)

[Second step](http://mygym2017.altervista.org/Screenshot__38_.png)

Instead of &day1, there should be the days he checked one by one.

Java source:

```
 static Global g = new Global();
private Button nextconfig;
private Spinner gruppo1,gruppo2;
private TextView giorno;
String[] array ;
String [] arrayTwo;
String idSelectedSpinner1, idSelectedSpinner2;
String id;
String name;
String[] days = {"Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"};

int[] daysBool;
int countClick=1;
int countButton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_starting_2);
    nextconfig = (Button) findViewById(R.id.nextconfig);
    gruppo1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gruppo1);
    gruppo2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.gruppo2);
    giorno=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.giorno1);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    int conta=intent.getIntExtra("countButton",0);
    countButton=conta;

    final SharedPreferences mPrefs = getSharedPreferences("userInfo", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    gruppo1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            idSelectedSpinner1=arrayTwo[position];
            Log.d("idSpinner:","" + arrayTwo[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });

    gruppo2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            idSelectedSpinner2=arrayTwo[position];
            Log.d("idSpinner:","" + arrayTwo[position]);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });



    final String url = g.getRootServer() + "/getMuscolarGroups.php";
    final String urlDays = g.getRootServer() + "/getTab.php?token="+mPrefs.getString("token",null);



    JsonObjectRequest myRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new JSONObject(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());

                if (response.has("errorCode")) {
                    try {

                        if (response.getInt("errorCode") == 0) {
                            JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
                            JSONArray muscolarGroups = data.getJSONArray("muscolarGroups");
                            array= new String [muscolarGroups.length()];
                            arrayTwo= new String [muscolarGroups.length()];
                            for (int i=0;i<muscolarGroups.length();i++){

                                JSONObject muscolarData = muscolarGroups.getJSONObject(i);
                                id = muscolarData.getString("id");
                                name = muscolarData.getString("name");

                                array[i]=name;
                                arrayTwo[i]=id;
                            }

                            addToSpinner(array);
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                }
            }) {
        };

        MySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(myRequest);
        Log.d("REQUEST", myRequest.toString());



    JsonObjectRequest myRequestDays = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, urlDays, new JSONObject(), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());

            if (response.has("errorCode")) {
                Log.d("response","" + response);
                try {

                    if (response.getInt("errorCode") == 0) {
                        JSONObject data = response.getJSONObject("data");
                        JSONObject tab = data.getJSONObject("tab");
                        daysBool = new int[tab.length() -1];
                        int monday = tab.getInt("monday");
                        int tuesday = tab.getInt("tuesday");
                        int wednesday = tab.getInt("wednesday");
                        int thursday = tab.getInt("thursday");
                        int friday = tab.getInt("friday");
                        int saturday = tab.getInt("saturday");

                        Log.d("Saturday", " "+saturday);

                        daysBool[0] = monday;
                        daysBool[1] = tuesday;
                        daysBool[2] = wednesday;
                        daysBool[3] = thursday;
                        daysBool[4] = friday;
                        daysBool[5] = saturday;

                        if (monday == 1) {
                            giorno.setText(days[0]);
                        } else if (tuesday == 1) {
                            giorno.setText(days[1]);
                        } else if (wednesday == 1) {
                            giorno.setText(days[2]);
                        } else if (thursday == 1) {
                            giorno.setText(days[3]);
                        }else if (friday == 1) {
                            giorno.setText(days[4]);
                        }else if (saturday == 1) {
                            giorno.setText(days[5]);
                        }


                    }

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {


    };

    MySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(myRequestDays);
    Log.d("REQUEST", myRequestDays.toString());




        nextconfig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {



                String url = g.getRootServer() + "/setTabGroup.php?token=" + mPrefs.getString("token",null) + "&groupOneId=" + idSelectedSpinner1 + "&groupTwoId=" + idSelectedSpinner2 +"&dayNumber=3";
                final Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
                //Parametri
                params.put("token","token"+mPrefs.getString("token",null));
                params.put("groupOneId","groupOneId"+idSelectedSpinner1);
                params.put("groupTwoId","groupTwoId" +idSelectedSpinner2);
                params.put("dayNumber","dayNumber" +idSelectedSpinner2);

                JsonObjectRequest myRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, new JSONObject(params), new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                        Log.d("RESPONSE", response.toString());

                        if (response.has("errorCode"))
                        {
                            try {


                                if (response.getInt("errorCode") == 0) {


                                    if (countClick==countButton){
                                        Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), Gruppo.class);
                                        intent.putExtra("daysTab",days);
                                        intent.putExtra("daysTabBool",daysBool);
                                        startActivity(intent);
                                        finish();
                                    }
                                    countClick++;

                                }
                            }  catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace();
                                }
                            }

                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

                        }
                    }) {
                    };

                MySingleton.getInstance(getBaseContext()).addToRequestQueue(myRequest);
                Log.d("REQUEST", myRequest.toString());
                }
            });
    }

    void getDays() {






    }


    void addToSpinner(String[] array) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.spinner_item, array);
        gruppo1.setAdapter(adapter);
        gruppo2.setAdapter(adapter);


        }


        @Override
        public void onBackPressed() {

            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), TabStarting.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

I will not look at your code snippet, because that's like asking me to do the work for you. Instead, I will answer you at a very high level, because this is really basic droid, and if you spend 5m on google, you'll find plenty of material on this topic.
The days of your first image are your 'state', each day can either be selected or not selected, and the views know that. Once you click the button, you start a new activity: at this point, pass the 'state' to the new activity with an intent. On the other side, on the created activity, you'll obtain the state, and by that info you'll populate your schedule with the selected days.
Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks man, I'll work on that. Btw I was just asking an algorithm, not the code

Comment: You're welcome! Either you use the word 'algorithm' erroneously, or I don't understand what you're asking. As I see it, you want to pass the selected days to the other activity, and once it knows which ones, you need to iterate over them, and for each have a UI part which allows the user to do this and that. Right? Like if user select Tuesday and Wednesday, then your UI will have both days, if user select all days, then your UI will have 7 entries (or have 7 prompts, one per day).

Comment: Exactly, I just need those days on the next activity and its value, so the API can send a request to the database e memorize group1&group2&dayNumber which is monday=1,tuesday=2 etc

Comment: Then I think my answer will help you: your state is either the selected days, so a list like {"Monday", Tuesday"} or a map with the selection, like { monday : selected, tuesday : selected, wednesday: unselected, thursday : unselected, friday : unselected, saturday : unselected, sunday : unselected}. Just pass it as I suggest, and there you are :)